# Does "abstruse" carry a positive or negative connotation?

Tags: word-usage, connotation

*Generally*, does the word "abstruse" give positive or negative (or neutral) connotations?

For example, "daedal" and "profound" would generally be considered a word with positive connotations, whereas "confusing" would have negative connotations, and "abstract" would be neutral.

I am aware that the entire sentence needs to be taken into context before we can determine the connotation, but with *just the word*, what connotation does "abstruse" give generally?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This word may be uncommon enough that its connotations end up being ultimately about individual opinion. None of the dictionaries I have just checked give any mention or relevant samples to indicate any inherent connotation in the word.

That said, *to me*, ‘abstruse’ has a definite ***negative*** connotation, like ‘obscure’ and ‘arcane’.

Most words that mean ‘difficult to understand’ tend to have a negative connotation, simply because making oneself clear and easy to understand is generally considered a virtue (unless you’re a philosopher, in which case I imagine the connotations are probably switched), while failing to do so is considered something undesirable.

The only words I can think of in this semantic category that generally have a positive connotation are *recondite* and (especially) *esoteric*. Both these words refer to something that is difficult to understand not because it is unclear and muddy, but because it is intricate, specialised, and rarely seen—and exactly because of those qualities, it is seen as being somewhat precious.

Comment: Hmm, isn't "intricate" *neutral*? From your last paragraphy, are you suggesting "intricate" has a positive connotation too?

Comment: I’d consider ‘intricate’ neutral in some contexts, and positive in others. If I describe the plot of a book as intricate, that will usually be a good thing. Only rarely would I use it if I wanted a negatively loaded word.

Comment: Why doesn't people upvote this question?

Comment: i disagree that 'obscure' has a negative connotation. it *can*, but it doesn't by default. by that i mean you can use it in a way that doesn't convey negativity at all. some words aren't so flexible. something is either known or obscure. not being known isn't "bad" in and of itself.

Comment: "...unless you're a philosopher." 

Excellent.